# Вывести текст в браузер без jsp

Tags: java, spring, mvc, spring-mvc

Всем привет.
Разбираюсь со Spring и некому подсказать/помочь, то прошу вас указать на мои пробелы, ошибки.
Есть задание: 1. Установите последнюю версию Spring Core и Sprint MVC . Версия : 5.0.8.RELEASE. Используйте переменные в pom.xml. 2. Создать простой IndexController , который возвращает обычный текст «Hello» для любого запроса. Используйте конфигурацию Java вместо конфигурации xml. Нужно вывести текст "Hello" в браузер не используя html/jsp.

```
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <spring.version>5.0.8.RELEASE</spring.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/jstl -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Зависимость от Servlet API 4.0.1 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Зависимости Spring -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.8.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <!--<dependency>-->
        <!--<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>-->
        <!--<artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>-->
        <!--<version>5.0.8.RELEASE</version>-->
    <!--</dependency>-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.8.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.8.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.8.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
   </dependencies>
```

Что тут не так. Запускаю Tomcat, подключил все артефакты, зависимости. При запуску сервера, пишет ошибка 404. Както может нужно переобразовать может.

[[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: попробуйте `@responseBody` переместить к возвращаемому типу метода.

Comment: это противоречит концепции MVC поскольку контроллер должен возвращать представление диспатчеру.

Answer (score 0):

1) Думаю в `WebConfig` вам не нужна функция `setupViewResolver()`,а так же `addViewControllers`, так как это указывают, что вы будете возвращать в качестве `view` `jsp`. 
(но нужно ли его удалять полность, не могу сказать точно, так как уже не работаю на джаве и немного забыл этот момент).

2) В вашем контроллере нужно указать какой-то `route`. `404` вы получаете по той причине, что нету адресса, по которому вы пытаетесь перейти.

К примеру:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/index", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public class IndexController { ... }
```

или же добавить `@RequestMapping` к самой функции.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/index", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public @ResponseBody String textHello() { return "json"; }
```

`produce` явно указывает, что функции этого контроллера будут возвращають `json`, а это собственно то, что вам нужно.

Так же, что бы не указывать в каждой функции `@ResponseBody`, вы можете изменить аннотацию `@Controller`, на `@RestController`.

После запуска `Tomcat` перейдите по адрессу `localhost:8080/index` или если вы указывали `Application context` при добавлении веб-сервера, тогда вам нужно влючить его в путь: `localhost:8080/{context_path}/index`.

Comment: изменил класс, в вебконфиге закоментил ненужное вышло        '@Controller
        public class IndexController {
        @RequestMapping(value = "/index", produces = 
        MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
        public @ResponseBody String textHello() { return "json"; }
    } '
Application context стоит /, запускаю томкет и все равно http://localhost:8080/index  404 ошибка

Comment: все пробовал, и ставил "@RestController" все также. может я чтото еще не добавил. вроде все зависимости есть. доавил еще json

Comment: @max210 а пробовали `localhost:8080/home/index`?

Comment: пробовал, все также без результатов. Добавил артефакты в проект, но ничего. Попробовать модет создать заново проект.

Comment: @max210 возможно вы порт изменили на другой, а не `8080`? Раз вы получаете 404 ошибку, значит веб сервер стартовал удачно.

Comment: с портом все ок, 8080. Я так понял что если запускать томкет, то нужно обязательно чтобы была страница для вывода сообщения. По другому реализовал и заработало.

Comment: @max210 как понять "страница для вывода сообщения"?

Comment: так как я пытался реализовать, то нужно создавать страницу html или jsp, чтобы она выводила меседж который я укажу. Тоесть страничку нужно булет создать. Выше я указал как реализовал и работает без томкета на спринге. Рылся в документации.

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.sobytylnik.hello;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    SpringApplication.run(Main.class, args);
}
}
```

также контроллер

```
package com.sobytylnik.hello;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class IndexController {
private static final String HELLO = "Hello";

@RequestMapping("/")
public String index(){
    return HELLO;
}
}
```

Запускаем мейн и вуаля, работает.